# MKNetworkKit - POST always returns 'The operation couldn't be completed'

Tags: objective-c, ios, mknetworkkit

I'm trying to talk to a WCF service from my iOS app using the MKNetworkKit. I always seem to get a 404 error even though the URL is valid. The operation completes if I use a GET instead of a POST (but I need it to be post).  Additionally, I have the same problem even if I supply valid params.

```
 MKNetworkOperation *op = [engine operationWithURLString:@"http://store.mystore.com/svc/InControl.svc"
                                                  params:nil                                                    
                                              httpMethod:@"POST"];
```

After I enqueue the above operation, I always end up with an error block being called. The error dumped to the console is `[The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 404.)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error code is 404, check if the endpoint is correct. Though HTTP is case insensitive, I believe WCF is not. So check if it is InControl or incontrol or inControl.